# Verificar activación plugin Wordpress mediante versión

Tags: wordpress

tengo creado un plugin con dos versiones diferentes, en las que dependiendo del sitio tengo que activar una versión u otra.

Lo que necesito es verificar, que si está activada una versión no se pueda activar la otra y viceversa.

Cuando se activa el plugin defino una variable para guardar la versión del plugin activo.

Este es el código que tengo en el main del plugin

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'miplugin_activacion' );
 
function miplugin_activacion() {


    // Añado la versión del plugin
    $plugin_data = get_file_data(__FILE__, array('Version' => 'Version'), false);
    $plugin_version = $plugin_data['Version'];

    /// Aquí debo comprobar si existe la variable y en el caso que existe su valor
    if (existe y no es "")
    {
        deactivate_plugins(plugin_basename(__FILE__));
    }
    else{
       activar
       define ( 'MI_PLUGIN_VERSION', $plugin_version );
    }
}

register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, 'miplugin_eliminacion');

function miplugin_s_eliminacion() {

    define ( 'MI_PLUGIN_VERSION',"");
}
```

Mi pregunta es ¿como puedo consultar esa variable existe y su valor para poder activar o no el plugin?

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ello puedes usar variables globales, al momento de activar el plugin globaliza la variable que contiene la versión del plugin, por ejemplo:

```
global $plugin_version;
```

Para comprobar que la variable existe y su valor puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
global $plugin_version;
if ( $plugin_version == 'Versión del plugin' ) {
   // Tus funciones
}
```

Aunque existen otras formas de hacerlo, como comprobar si un plugin esta activo usando la función `is_plugin_active()` de wordpress, por ejemplo:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

if ( is_plugin_active( 'tu-plugin/tu-plugin.php' ) ) {
   // Tus Funciones
}
```

Dependerá de ti la forma en la que lo hagas, pero con esto te puedes dar una idea.

Comment: Muchas gracias,

Comment: Si mi respuesta te funciono, agradecería que la marques como aceptada